# Necesito convertir un campo de un bindinglist en combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Este es el código que no está funcionando:

```
public class DetalleTurnoPersonal
    {
        public string Nombre  { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha_Entrada { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Hora_Entrada { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha_Salida { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Hora_Salida { get; set; }
        public string Sector { get; set; }
        public int IDSeccion { get; set; }
        public int IDEmpresa { get; set; }


    }
```

y por el otro lado la tomo con un bindinglist

```
private readonly BindingList<DetalleTurnoPersonal> misDetalles = new BindingList<DetalleTurnoPersonal>();
        public FrmTurnosTransferPersonal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

DetalleTurnoPersonal miDetalle = new DetalleTurnoPersonal();

 miDetalle.Nombre = NombrePersona;
                miDetalle.Hora_Entrada = TimeSpan.Parse(horaEntradaComboBox.Text);
                miDetalle.Fecha_Entrada = Convert.ToDateTime(FechadateTimePicker.Value.ToShortDateString());
                miDetalle.Hora_Salida = TimeSpan.Parse(HoraSalidacomboBox.Text);
                miDetalle.Fecha_Salida = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString());
                miDetalle.Sector = Personalxnombre.Sector;
                miDetalle.IDSeccion = personalxnombre.IDSeccion;
                miDetalle.IDEmpresa = UsuarioLogueado.IDEmpresa;
                misDetalles.Add(miDetalle);
```

el campo que deseo que se visualice en la grilla como combobox es midetalle.sector

Comment: Agrega información del error o comportamiento del programa para ayudar al diagnóstico

Answer (score 0):

intenta poniendo algo asi:

```
combobox1.DataSource=misDetalles;
combobox1.DisplayMember="Sector";
```

Espero esto pueda ayudarte